# discord music bot is connecting and accepting the url but its giving me no audio

Tags: discord, discord.py, audio-player

import discord
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_search import YoutubeSearch
from typing import Union

intents = discord.Intents.all()

#(commands)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
# Check if the user is in a voice channel
if ctx.author.voice is None:
await ctx.send("You need to be in a voice channel to use this command.")
return

```
# Get the voice channel of the user
channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

# Connect to the voice channel
voice_client = await channel.connect()

await ctx.send(f"Joined {channel}")
```

@bot.command()
async def search(ctx, *, query):
# check if the user is in a voice channel
if ctx.author.voice is None:
await ctx.send("You need to be in a voice channel to use this command.")
return

```
# no results
results = YoutubeSearch(query, max_results=5).to_dict()

if not results:
    await ctx.send("No results found.")
    return

for i, video in enumerate(results, 1):
    await ctx.send(f"{i}. {video['title']}")
```

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, index_or_url: Union[int, str]):

```
if isinstance(index_or_url, int):
    index = index_or_url
else:
    # Handles the case where the argument is a URL so it wont give error
    url = index_or_url
    # more code for playing from URLs goes here
    return

try:
    index = int(index)
except ValueError:
    await ctx.send("Invalid selection. Please provide a valid number.")
    return

results = YoutubeSearch(ctx.message.content[7:], max_results=5).to_dict()

if not results or index < 1 or index > len(results):
    await ctx.send("Invalid selection. Please choose a number within the provided range.")
    return

selected_video = results[index - 1]
url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={selected_video['id']}"

# Join the voice channel if not already in
if ctx.voice_client is None:
    if ctx.author.voice:
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
        return

# Plays audio
voice_client = ctx.voice_client
voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url), after=lambda e: print('done', e))

await ctx.send(f"Now playing: {selected_video['title']}")
```

@bot.command()
async def pause(ctx):
await ctx.send("Paused the playback.")

@bot.command()
async def resume(ctx):
await ctx.send("Resumed the playback.")

@bot.command()
async def skip(ctx):
await ctx.send("Skipped the current song.")

bot.run(